# Variable for SCP command in script

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, scp, hosts

I'm trying to write a script that will check what is the last modified/created file on the server, then copy it to my homedirectory on this server and then copy this file from node to my local machine.

I would like to point out, that I am learning how to do this, so I don't have skill at all.

Here is my script, don't look at "fr" option as it's for testing things localy.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -xv

dcma=some_server_name1
dcfr=some_server_name2
echo "FR czy MA?"

read dc

if [ "${dc,,}" == "fr" ]
then
echo "Wybrales Frankfurt!"
cd test/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; cp $out ../
elif [ "${dc,,}" == "ma" ]
then
echo "Wybrales Boston!"
cmd=$( ssh -t $dcma ' cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/ ; ls -1tr ~/ | tail -n 1 ' )
cmdv=$( echo "$cmd" )
echo "Ostatnie wybrane hosty na serwerze: $cmdv"
scp -r some_server_name1:~/"$cmdv" .
fi
```

Script is failing on SCP command, as it's says that there is no such file or directory mentioned by $cmdv variable.

Here is output with set -xv.

```bsh
user-VirtualBox:~/hosty-skrypt$ ./hosty-v8 



dcma=some_server_name1
+ dcma=some_server_name1
dcfr=some_server_name2
+ dcfr=some_server_name2
echo "FR czy MA?"
+ echo 'FR czy MA?'
FR czy MA?

read dc
+ read dc
ma

if [ "${dc,,}" == "fr" ]
then
echo "Wybrales Frankfurt!"
cd test/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; cp $out ../
elif [ "${dc,,}" == "ma" ]
then
echo "Wybrales Boston!"
cmd=$( ssh -t $dcma ' cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/ ; ls -1tr ~/ | tail -n 1 ' )
cmdv=$( echo "$cmd" )
echo "Ostatnie wybrane hosty na serwerze: $cmdv"
scp -r some_server_name1:~/"$cmdv" .
fi
+ '[' ma == fr ']'
+ '[' ma == ma ']'
+ echo 'Wybrales Boston!'
Wybrales Boston!
 ssh -t $dcma ' cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/ ; ls -1tr ~/ | tail -n 1 ' 
++ ssh -t some_server_name1 ' cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/ ; ls -1tr ~/ | tail -n 1 '
some_username@some_server_name1's password: 
Connection to some_server_name1 closed.
+ cmd=$'hosts.merged.1558094140821\r'
 echo "$cmd" 
++ echo $'hosts.merged.1558094140821\r'
+ cmdv=$'hosts.merged.1558094140821\r'
' echo 'Ostatnie wybrane hosty na serwerze: hosts.merged.1558094140821
Ostatnie wybrane hosty na serwerze: hosts.merged.1558094140821
' .cp -r 'some_server_name1:~/hosts.merged.1558094140821
some_username@some_server_name1's password: 
: No such file or directoryhosts.merged.1558094140821
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Also I can't place this script on target machines as it's against company policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution.

Turns out, that variable had an attached "\r" at the end.

I solved this by using tr command.

```bsh
cmd=$( ssh -t some_server_name1 ' cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/ ; ls -1tr ~/ | tail -n 1 ' )
cmdv=$( echo "$cmd" | tr -d '\r' )
```

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the directory /home/some_username/hosts.merged.1558094140821/ does not exist or does not have read/execute permissions by 'some_username'. Might be a good idea to specify the desired username to scp, just in case the wrong user is being accessed on the remote server.

For example:

```
scp -r remote_username@some_server_name1:~/"$cmdv" .
```

Comment: Username, is taken from ssh config file. I have tried, with full path. Same error.

Comment: OK, and have you checked that the user specified definitely has read and execute permissions to that folder..?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, prermissions are correct.

Comment: Can you try verbose output with scp:
scp -rv remote_username@some_server_name1:~/"$cmdv" .

Answer (score 0):

Your script would fetch you the last modified file name from location `/opt/automation/repository/hosts/` on server `some_servername1`

And when you doing `scp` you are ignoring the path and fetching the file name.

Please change the command from

```
scp -r some_server_name1:~/"$cmdv"
```

to

```
scp -r some_server_name1:/opt/automation/repository/hosts/"$cmdv"
```

Hope this solves the issue.

Comment: It is not fetching file from that directory. If you read script, it fetch file from `/opt/automation/repository/hosts/` AND is copying it to my home directory on the server as you can see in this line:
`cd /opt/automation/repository/hosts/ ; out=$( ls -1tr | tail -n 1 ) ; sudo cp $out ~/`